# 1 query depends on another query codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, many-to-many

I have a table tbparent_module,tbsub_module and a junction table called tbmodule_pairing wherein it contains the IDs of the 2 tables (tbparent_module,tbsub_module)

On my controller I called a model that will query all the parent module and will display it on the view. I already did this but my problem is, I need to display also its sub module.

*Example of output*

```
Parent Module 1
     Sub Mod 1
     Sub Mod 2
     Sub Mod 3

Parent Module 2
     Sub Mod 1
     Sub Mod 2
     Sub Mod 3

Parent Module 3
     Sub Mod 1
     Sub Mod 2
     Sub Mod 3
```

This is my code as of now

**view**

```
foreach($module as $result){
      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tbsub_module` where parent_id='$result->id'");
      while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
         echo $row['subcateg_name'];
      }
}
```

I know this is wrong. But this the only way I know to solve my problem. I want to follow the MVC rule and I also I want to use CodeIgniter's library

Answer (score 0):

Go to this CI documentation http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html 
There are all DB methods available in CI.

Here is perhaps working (not tested) way to do your query..

```
$query = $this->db->get('modules');  ## SELECTIN all records from modules table
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $query2 = $this->db->get_where('tbsub_module', array('parent_id' => $row->id));
        foreach ($query2->result() as $row2)
        {
            echo $row2->subcateg_name;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you want to use CI DB active record for selecting data check the http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select
(there are all methods for the query with examples - select, where, order, limit, like , etc..)

Comment: Thanks! Actually I know how to use the active record and the database library of CodeIgniter. But my problem is , I can't figure out the logic for my problem.

The code that I've posted is from my view page, actually I don't want to query there. but I don't have any idea how can I retrieve my records wherein the query is depending on anothers results.

As you can see it is in the inside of foreach loop. The $result there is generated by a controller.

Thanks for the reply by the way

Comment: CI is MVC framework..
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

All queries must be in Model, Controller get the data from Model and give it to your view file..

Comment: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

See the Load View function its called at Controller, there you may put second param. containing Data which may comes from the model..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the data to your view from your controller. You're essentially breaking the whole idea of MVC there. The query should be in the model, which is called by the controller then passed to the view. I won't address the query (am tired...) but this is basically what you want.

Controller:

```
function whateverTheViewIs()
{
    $this->load->model('categories');
    $data['subCatName'] = $this->categories->getSubcats();
    $this->load->view('viewName',$data);
}
```

Model categories:

```
function getSubCats()
{
   run your query here, return array of whatever data you need.
}
```

viewName:

```
foreach($subCat as $subcateg)
{
    echo $subcateg['subcateg_name'];
}
```

if you need the module too you could load it into another $data['whatever'] array in the controller and pass it the same way.